# How can I tell Flask not to add host/scheme info to my redirect?

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, werkzeug

I want to use Flask to redirect RTMP streams, where the new stream name is contained in the `Location` header of a `30x` redirect.  However, Flask always adds the host/scheme URL info to my redirect:

```
@app.route("/redirect")
def root():
    return redirect("new-stream-name")
```

Results in:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 FOUND
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 237
Location: http://localhost:5000/new-stream-name
Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.9
Date: Sat, 02 May 2015 19:31:28 GMT
```

Where I want the Location to just be:

```
Location: new-stream-name
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using [nginx-rtmp stream redirects](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#on_play) to control how my publishers/viewers authenticate with streams.

UPDATE:

The solution was rather easy with subclassing `Response`:

```
from flask import Response

class FixedLocationResponse(Response):
    autocorrect_location_header = False


@app.route("/redirect")
def root():
    return redirect("new-stream-name", Response=FixedLocationResponse)
```

Results in:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 FOUND
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 237
Location: new-stream-name
Server: Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.9
Date: Sat, 02 May 2015 19:31:28 GMT
```

Comment: No, according to the standard, the Location header must be an absolute URL: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-14.30

Comment: What client are you using that needs a relative Location header?

Comment: @nathancahill see my edit, I'm using HTTP callbacks from nginx-rtmp to authenticate stream publishers/viewers.

Comment: Since you have an answer you should answer you own question and accept it.